# iOS - NSUrlConnection direct connection is not

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, nsurlconnection

Performing Web Service connection `[Connection start]` saying, the web service is called from the method called in each directly;

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{}
```

Link them like method. However, other methods are calling a web service connection function after treatment, although open connection function, turn to ask you at the first function works as a web service method, and then click "didReceiveResponse" method of logging into the web service returns data.

The mention of this at the start connection as opposed to "didReceiveResponse" Can I make an arrangement that will allow to enter?